# CrateDB drop column not working and throwing an error

Tags: cratedb

Hello stackoverflow so I have a cratedb database instance with about 3 million records in my table. I am trying to run the following command.

```
ALTER TABLE "transactions_v2" DROP COLUMN "itemPrices";
```

However I end up with this error

```
Error!

SQLParseException[line 1:62: mismatched input 'COLUMN' expecting {'.', 'PARTITION', 'DROP'}]
```

Any ideas why I can't seem to drop the column?

Answer (score 0):

So cratedb does not support `DROP COLUMN` which is why I was getting the error.